# How to set next and previous posts manually in WordPress single post?

Tags: wordpress

Actually, i want to set next and previous posts manually while editing the single post.

Suppose that:
The previous post title is "Lecture 1"
The Current editing post title is "Lecture 2"
The next post title is "Lecture 3"

I know this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/organize-series/

but it creates a series and i want next previous post manually set in every post.

Comment: Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and try to edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can retrieve the actual post number and create a link to ?p=N-1 and ?p=N+1 where N is the number of you actual post.
https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Comment: Thanks Brother but if I prepare 100 lectures and i need to add a new lecture into the place of 54th lecture, then what should i do? Because I want to add a new lecture into the place of 54th lecture and want to move 54th lecture to 55th place and onward upto hundred.